# Sort database query by column and then randomly

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Let's say you have a model for Items with an attribute of Votes. Here might be some sample data:

```
Item, Votes
-----------
Red     4
Blue    5
Black   5   
Green   4
Cyan    5
Yellow  4
Orange  4
```

I want a scope that first sorts it by Votes:

```
Item, Votes
-----------
Orange  4
Green   4
Yellow  4
Red     4
Blue    5
Black   5   
Cyan    5
```

And then randomizes it within each vote cohort:

```
Item, Votes
-----------
Green   4
Red     4
Orange  4
Yellow  4
Black   5   
Blue    5
Cyan    5
```

And then limits it to the first two results.

I've tried this:

```
scope :options, -> { order('random()').order("votes asc").limit 2 }
```

and this:

```
scope :options, -> { order("votes asc").order('random()').limit 2 }
```

But neither works as expected. The first version seems completely random and the second version is not random at all.

Comment: When you say "the first two results", do you mean the first result from each group (4 and 5 votes)? If you mean the first two from the lowest group, your second solution works: `scope :options, -> { order('votes ASC, random()').limit(2) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the item model I made this method:

```
def rand_value
  self.votes + Random.rand
end
```

And then in the controller I am using this query:

```
@items = @experiment.items.sort_by { |item| [item.rand_value] }
```

This seems to be working like I wanted. The first items on the list are always the ones with the least votes, but within each cohort they are randomized. The only disadvantage of this is that it's not limited to two results.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what you want, you have two options. If you want the first two in the complete result (highlighted below), your second solution works. If however, you want the first row of each group, you'll need to modify your query somewhat (as shown below:)

---

**First rows of complete result:**

```
scope :options, -> { order('votes ASC, random()').limit(2) }
```

will select the following rows:

```
Item, Votes
-----------
Green   4  *
Red     4  *
Orange  4
Yellow  4
Black   5   
Blue    5
Cyan    5
```

---

**First row of each group:**

```
scope :options, -> { select('DISTINCT ON (votes) *').order('votes ASC, random()').limit(2) }
```

will select the following rows:

```
Item, Votes
-----------
Green   4  *
Red     4
Orange  4
Yellow  4
Black   5  *   
Blue    5
Cyan    5
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as the sorting is concerned, there's a great gem called 'Ransack' (https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) that allows for dynamic sorting of your data-sets.  I'm afraid I can't offer much in the way of your other concerns but hopefully this helps with the sorting!